# Show an image for a short time in ImageView and then revert back to original image

Tags: android, image, imageview, android-imageview

In a simple app I have 2 buttons and an image underneath them:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/open"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/open"
    android:onClick="openCar"
    android:text="@string/open_car" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/car_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/closed_car"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

[image: foto]

The current button click handler just changes the image (to `opened_car`):

```
public void openCar(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
            getString(R.string.car_opened), 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    mNotificationManager.cancel(CommonConstants.NOTIFICATION_ID);

    mCarImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.opened_car);
}
```

As an Android programming newbie I wonder, what is the best way to revert back to the original image (back to `closed_car`) after some time?

Also I wonder if there are some more impressive ways in core Android (i.e. without requiring any additional libraries) to swap images - like fading in/out?

Comment: You coult put 2 imageview on top of each other, the top one being invisible, then make it visible only the time you need it, it will save you multiple calls to setImageResource (which can be quite slow). It also applies if you want to add animations between your images : http://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html

Comment: Thanks +1, but I thought that only `findViewById` calls are slow - because they parse XML?

Comment: findViewById can be slow, the deal is to do it only once (in the onCreate by ex) and cache the view in a local variable. The goal is to do the heavy stuff (initialization, setting the images, etc) at the beginning of the app to not slow it down while running. When you change the visibility of your element, everything is already loaded, and you just tell what to draw or not ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do that is to use Handlers

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // Do something after 100ms delay

  }
}, 100);
```